# Writing Bash Script to Log Out if Incorrect upon Login. Need guidance

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, logout

I am trying to write a Bash Script that will log the user out if they cannot get the security question.

I am needing to find either an array or multiple if conditions to reflect this. I know there are a lot of sub-stuff such as stopping any override input(CTRL+Z, etc).

Below is the script I have so far, and I am getting the error below. I am not wanting the answer, just direction of what to look for. It doesn't even prompt the security question, just goes straight to logging the root user out in this case.

```
./txtscript: line 13: [: =: unary operator expected
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is your name?"
read ISNAME
if [ $ISNAME = "root" ];
then
    echo "Nice to meet you, root."
    echo "Login as root" | mail -s "Login for root" root
    echo "Next for the Security Question! "  
fi

echo "What is the codename?"
if [ $codename = "Cole Server" ];
then
    echo "Hello, Welcome"
else
    echo "Away from me, Not Root"
    echo "Unauthorized" | mail -s "INTRUDER ALERT" root
    pkill -KILL -u $ISNAME;
fi
```

*****UPDATE*******

Alright, So I got that part fixed. Now the script has the following.

echo "What is the codename?"
read CODEAME
if [ $CODENAME = "Cole Server" ];
then

When I run the script, I get the error "./txtscript: line 14: [: =: unary operator expected"

Line 14 is:  if [ $CODENAME = "Cole Server" ];

In general, I have not even found a good website/article that really explains the unary operator expected error, so I have no idea what it means. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always quote your variables unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: You never read the codename.

Comment: I just realized it. That is why I like having people look over my coding. I would of never bothered to check that part lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem is that `$codename` is not filled in.

So line 13 is running:

```
if [ = "Cole Server" ];  # note: the $codename was expanded to emptiness
```

What you want to write in your script is:

```
if [ "$codename" = "Cole Server"];
```

This will evaluate as

```
if [ "" = "Cole Server"];
```

Which is at least syntactically valid. You still need to actually assign to `codename` somewhere, which you're currently not doing.

However, I think this whole approach is probably wrong-headed.
You are giving them an interactive bash session, and there are all sorts of things they can do there - like press `Ctrl+Z` to suspend it.

This is fine as a fun little game, but if you are trying to do serious security, I worry (:

Comment: HA, Newb Mistake. I completey overlooked lol. Always love having fresh eyes review my coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had the read $CODEAME set not $CODENAME as well that was causing the issue.

This is fixed and working perfect. Now I will be implementating a trap command to stop people from trying to bypass the script..

If anyone has any resources or example traps to stop CTRL C, CTRL Z and the SIG terms, Let me know!